# I am unable to run Quick sort for singly Linked list. m not able to put the condition for recursive call in quick sort function

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, quicksort, singly-linked-list

```
/* SORTING SINGLY LINKED LIST USING QUICK SORT ALGORITHM */

/*Function to get the pivot node*/

node *partition(node *start, node *end)
{
    if (start == NULL || start->next == NULL)   //If one node or no node is present
    {
        return start;
    }

    node *pivot, *cur, *pre, *temp;
    pivot = pre = start;
    cur = start->next;

    while (1)
    {
        if (cur == end)
        {
            break;  //while loop breaks
        }
        else if (cur->data < pivot->data) 
        {
            temp = cur;
            pre->next = cur->next;
            cur = cur->next;    //Here swapping is done basically
            temp->next = pre;
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            pre = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
    return pivot; //pivot node returned to PartitionNode in quick sort function
}
```

```
/*quicksort recursive ; what conditions do I need to apply here so the it can work properly
recursion call is not working as expected; please I ask you correct this it's been 2 days now stuck on same problem */ 

void *quicksort(node *head, node *tail)
{
    node *start = head;
    node *PartitionNode = partition(start, tail->next); //partition function called to get pivot node
    node *list2 = PartitionNode->next;

    while (start != PartitionNode && list2 != tail)  //not working and so much confusing please help
    {
        while (start->next != PartitionNode)
        {
            quicksort(start, PartitionNode);
            node *PartitionNode = partition(start, PartitionNode);
        }

        while (list2 != tail) //list2 start will PartitionNode->next
        {
            quicksort(PartitionNode->next, tail->next);
            node *PartitionNode = partition(PartitionNode->next, tail->next);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: quick sort function above is wrong and messed up. Can someone please send me the right function for quick sort.

Comment: Raminder, quicksort algorithm is well known and you could find lots of examples online.  Here is one I found that also has some data passed in.  Maybe you could try this one and see if it works for you.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    node *partition(node *start, node *end) //pivot is first element of linked list
    {
    node *pivot_prev = start;
    node *current = start;
    int pivot = start->data;
    start = start->next;
    while (start != end->next)
    {
    if (start->data < pivot)
    {
        pivot_prev = current;
        int temp = current->data;
        current->data = start->data;
        start->data = temp;
        current = current->next;
     }
     start = start->next;
     }
     return pivot_prev; //current not will not be returned as current not is already at its right place
      }

    void quicksort(node *start, node *end)
    {
    if (start == end)
    {
    return;
    }
    node *prev = partition(start, end);
   

    quicksort(start, prev);
    quicksort(prev->next, end);
    }
```

Comment: (Even seeing this looks cleaner:) Please describe what is changed and why that makes a difference.

Comment: @greybeard the issue was with rescursive call n pivot address that required to sort linked list. In previous quick sort func, recursive call condition neither is initiating proper nor terminating. Moreover Pivot address returning frm partition func is also incorrect. So i dry run the algo. In new algo, i returned a proper pivot n then called quick sort func recursively, intially starting frm head upto tail n got 1st pivot addr frm it n then quick sort run for start to pivot and a quick sort from piviot->next upto tail. This process repeats recurisively and terminates when start reaches end.